# ergMargins error: non-conformable argument and structural zeros/ones

Tags: r, margins, network-analysis, statnet, ergm

I am quite an ergm newbie, so forgive me if the answer to my question is obvious to you.
I modeled my network using ergms and try to facilitate interpretability by using the AMEs of ergms (function: ergm.AME()). Here, R returns two error messages:

1. Error in t(x) %*% cbcoef : non-conformable arguments
   and an additional warning message:
2. In edge.prob2(model) :  There are structural zeros or ones. For these dyads, the predicted probabilities are not valid and must be manually replaced by 0 or 1, respectively.

I tried to find questions on both topics on stack overflow but could not find any. Do you know what the problem is? I do not have any problems when calculating the models using ergm.

For these models the code works:

```
model1 <- ergm(
  network ~ edges + mutual + gwidegree(decay=1, fixed=TRUE) +
    gwodegree(decay=1, fixed=TRUE),
  estimate = "MPLE"
)
model2 <- ergm(
  network ~ edges + mutual + gwidegree(decay=1, fixed=TRUE) +
    gwodegree(decay=1, fixed=TRUE) + gwesp(decay=1, fixed=TRUE),
  estimate = "MPLE"
)

model3 <- ergm.AME(model1, "edges")
model4 <- ergm.AME(model2, "edges")
```

However, when using a more complex model, the error messages occur:

```
model5 <- ergm(
  network ~ edges + mutual + gwidegree(decay=1, fixed=TRUE) +
    gwodegree(decay=1, fixed=TRUE) + gwesp(decay=1, fixed=TRUE) +
    edgecov(network1)  + edgecov(network2) + edgecov(network3) +
    edgecov(network4)     + nodeifactor("chronic") +
    nodeofactor("chronic")  +nodeifactor("nas") +
    nodeofactor("nas") + nodeofactor("sup") + 
    nodematch("chronic") + nodematch("nas") + 
    nodematch("gender") + nodefactor("gender"),
  estimate = "MPLE"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you expand the question with the output of `summary(model5)`? There might be several reasons for that, but the one I'm suspecting is that your model has some of the coefficient estimates at `Inf` or `-Inf`. This trips the calculation of dyadic tie probabilities which are necessary to compute AMEs. Generally speaking, you may have not enough "variability" in your data to estimate a model that complex.

Thus the solution for you would be:

1. Investigate if there are coef estimates at Inf or -Inf.
2. Re-specify the model by

   - Making it simpler by dropping problematic terms, or
   - I'm suspecting that perhaps some combinations of values of nodal attributes are empty. If so, look into the distributions of these attributes and perhaps consider joining some categories.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Indeed, I have one coefficient estimate with -Inf. Since I am modeling across multiple networks, I cannot exclude the network term (the Inf is only in this specific network!). Since ergm is still providing me with estimates, I hoped for the same when calculating AMEs. Or is this impossible?

Comment: @Amelie Are you fitting the same specification to multiple networks separately or have a pooled model to all networks in one go? From the code in the question I think the former rather than the latter, correct? It will be impossible to calculate AMEs with ergMargins for a model that has any coef at Inf or -Inf.

Comment: I am fitting the same specification to multiple network separately, indeed. Alright, thank you for your answer, that helps a lot!